# Develop new output using cumulative distribution function in R

Tags: r, statistics, threshold

Context: Each part is a part in an engine, and the overall time it takes before each part needs to be 'repaired/fixed/adjusted/etc' is what I am basically wanting to generate. Think of the variables as three different engines. There are recommended 'time thresholds' that indicates what should happen to each part (similar to the oil change analogy and how they determine when to bring in next - x amount of miles, etc.). I need to use actual data (hours in service) to create new threshold ranges (less than x hours, greater than x hrs) for each part for each engine.

Example of output (made up thresholds):
part 1 -- x <10,000 hr, x = 10 - 16,000 hrs, and x > 16,000hrs

I am new to the concept but this is the problem and the data is below:

I have tried some preliminary analysis to measure the distribution of the data for each variable (mind you the data is in hours). Each row is a part and the hours shows how well that part is performing until it needs to go into the shop. Similarly to a 'recommended time to get your oil change', I need to use actual part performance data to come up with a new threshold range in hours.

```
## Random Matrix - Three Variables - 50 rows ##
trial <- matrix(sample(70000, replace = TRUE), ncol=4, nrow = 100)
colnames(trial) <- c('Part_Num', 'A (hours)', 'B (hours)', 'C (hours)')
trial <- as.data.frame(trial)
trial$Part_Num <- sample(c('A23ed', 'dfsa34','gsafa43', 'fsafa32', 'gasfa6'), 100, replace = TRUE) #sample random values

plot(ecdf(df[,"MFP"]))
```

If for each Variable (A, B, and C) I have a recommended range in time of < 10k, 10 - 14k, and >14k hrs to do something to the part, how can I use cumalitive distribution function to come up with a new range for each part in the three variables?

Comment: I have to admit that I'm not quite following what you're trying to do. You have "*three variables that have a recommended threshold to do something with each variable*". What does that mean? To do something with each variable? Do what? To which variable and how? What does `Part_Num` denote? Which CDF are you referring to? You mention a range in time: Which time?

Comment: Ok, a few things: SO has some [specific rules for homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) that you should take a look at. There's nothing wrong with asking HW questions but we'd like to see some effort on your part at solving the question; otherwise this may be interpreted as an unfavourable "Somebody do the (home)work for me" question. Secondly, I still don't understand what threshold you are trying to estimate/determine. A threshold for what, doing what? And it's still not clear what `Part_Num` does.

Comment: [continued] Let's take a step back: You've got multiple `A`, `B`, `C` values for every unique `Part_Num`. What do these values denote? What are you trying to do with these values? What role does the "recommended threshold" play in this?

Comment: My apologies - I do not want to come off as do my HW for me. Context: Each part is a part in an engine, and the overall time it takes before each part needs to be 'repaired/fixed/adjusted/etc' is what I am basically wanting to generate. Think of the variables as three different engines. There are recomendded 'time thresholds' that indicates what should happen to each part (similar to the oil change analogy and how they determine when to bring in next - x amount of miles, etc.). I need to use actual data (hours in service) to create new threshold ranges (less than x hours, greater than x hrs)..

Comment: Ok we're getting somewhere. All these details should go into the main body of your post; comments are transient & might get deleted. So let me see if I get this correct: The values in `A`, `B`, `C` for every unique `Part_Num` are simulated time-to-failure values for three different engines. Somehow you want to determine a "time threshold" for every engine for every `Part_Num`. What determines such a threshold? You could simply take the median, which is the time where 50% of the engine parts would've failed. If that's not good enough, what determines a "better" threshold?

Comment: Sorry - I will edit the main body of the question. I first used the min, median (or avg) and max - what killed it were the outliers for the max threshold. I was told to use a different method for this problem (that's where CDF came into play). I want to use another form of statistical analysis to calculate a min and adjusted max thresholds (say 75% the max) based on actual and output from CDF. If CDF is not the best way, by all means I don't need to use that..

Comment: What are A, B and C? It seems to me that you can benefit from having a _long_ table instead of a wide one, but won't know for sure until you explain what are those variables

Comment: A B and C are three different engine types - I'm thinking of just doing a distribution model and setting a quartile based on 25/75% of the distribution given the avg - thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that might give you some ideas.

Since we're dealing with time-to-failure data, it makes sense to explore data in the context of [survival analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis). The idea is to visualise the survival probability of every machine part in every engine as a function of time. A good starting point is to take a look at the corresponding [Kaplan-Meier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplan%E2%80%93Meier_estimator). We will make use of the `survival` and `survminer` libraries that provide all the necessary analysis and plotting methods.

We first reshape data from wide to long, and ensure that data are in a tidy and suitable format for the downstream survival analysis.

#### Data tidying

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- trial %>%
    gather(engine, time, -Part_Num) %>%
    mutate(engine = str_remove(engine, " \\(hours\\)")) %>%
    mutate(
        status = 1,
        time = as.numeric(time),
        Part_Num = as.factor(Part_Num),
        engine = as.factor(engine))
```

We now calculate the Kaplan-Meier (KM) estimates and show the corresponding KM survival curves for every machine part for every engine.

#### Survival curves

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ engine + Part_Num, data = df)

gg <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = df, risk.table = FALSE)
gg$plot +
    theme_minimal() +
    facet_grid(engine ~ Part_Num) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]

#### Optimal cutpoint

In a first step you should take a look at the mean/median survival times for every machine component in every engine. The output object of `survfit` will give you these details, along with 95% (by default) confidence intervals.

Another interesting possibility to determine an optimal time cutpoint in the presence of a continuous variable that characterises every machine part in every engine is to use [maximally selected ranked statistics (maxstat)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maxstat/vignettes/maxstat.pdf); such a method is conveniently provided by `survminer`.

In the interest of me not doing your homework, you should take a look at `?survival::survfit` and `?survminer::surv_cutpoint` to see how to implement such approaches. It should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Thank you for walking me through your thought process - I really do appreicate it! As far as thresholding goes, I just used the median per part and then used +/- 1 standard deviation from the mean as when set a threshold time to fix (instead of anything in between 95% CI. I hope that makes sense, I don't see why that wouldn't be accepted for the assignment. I'm not familiar with maximally selected ranked statistics (maxstat).